# IE7 not expanding div correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to get an expanding div to appear correctly in IE7. What is happening, is that the div will appear behind the button instead of pushing the div down to accommodate the textarea box. I have tried combinations of clear, position, but still the same. Can someone check my code and point out my error. It works fine in IE8 & FF (Even IE6 :-)) just 7 that is causing problem. Many thanks

Demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/P5NQt/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `height` property from the `.fb-input-right-conradio-back` rule.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2jBbu/

---

Something else (*irrelevant to the original issue*), i would suggest you wrap the `Yes` text in a `<label>` with a `for` attribute, so the the whole text will act as a button for the checkbox..

```
<label for="messagetick2">Yes</label>
```